# How to update multiple rows within the same table in one SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to update two values in the same column, same table on different rows in one process.  The DefaultForAxisID tags which CategoryID is the primary vs secondary.

In the **BEFORE and AFTER** example I need to set the following two things simultaneously to avoid errors.

1. DefaultforAxisID = 2 where ProcedureCodeID = 195837 and CategoryID = 21
2. DefaultforAxisID = null WHERE ProcedureCodeID = 195837 and CategoryID = 22

To put into words, I need to swap the DefaultforAxisID's for CategoryID 21 and 22.

---

When I execute **Fig A**, I get following error (**Fig B**), but it does update the column. I probably could follow it up with a second update but I just don't feel comfortable that it's throwing an error and thus am exploring alternative.

**Figure A.**

```sql
UPDATE ProcedureCodeCategory
SET DefaultForAxisID = null
WHERE CategoryID = 22 and ProcedureCodeID = 195837
```

****Figure B:****
`[Code: 50000, SQL State: S0001]  Clearing an existing default is not permitted. Please select a new deafault for this procedure if this is no longer valid.  [Script position: 1795 - 1805]`

---

When I figure out how to achieve this, I will create a stored procedure in the database, and incorporate it into a Python Function.

## **BEFORE**

| ProcedureCodeCategoryID | ProcedureCodeID | CategoryID | IsInherited | DefaultforAxisID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 998743 | 195837 | 21 | false | (null) |
| 998509 | 195837 | 22 | false | 2 |
| 998742 | 195837 | 314 | false | (null) |
| 998510 | 195837 | 316 | false | 3 |

## **AFTER**

| ProcedureCodeCategoryID | ProcedureCodeID | CategoryID | IsInherited | DefaultforAxisID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 998743 | 195837 | 21 | false | 2 |
| 998509 | 195837 | 22 | false | (null) |
| 998742 | 195837 | 314 | false | (null) |
| 998510 | 195837 | 316 | false | 3 |

Comment: FYI Having such huge heading doesn't make it more readable... hence why I reduced them. Also the error shows better quoted than as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple case expression can work here easily enough.

```
update YourTable
set DefaultforAxisID = case CategoryID when 21 then 2 when 22 then NULL else DefaultforAxisID end 
where CategoryID in (21, 22)
```

Comment: I ran this, it did not update `DefaultForAxisID`  = 2 when `CategoryID` = 21. It left `DefaultforAxisID = null`

Comment: Ahh yes...my bad. I suspect you really want a more dynamic version but your requirement is unclear.

Comment: I updated my question; I hope this clarifies things. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: I changed the Where to WHERE ProcedureCodeID = 195837 and it worked!